# Networkx create graph from adjacency matrix without edge weights

Tags: networkx

When I call `G = nx.convert_matrix.from_numpy_array(A, create_using=nx.DiGraph)`, where `A` is a 0-1 adjacency matrix, the resulting graph automatically contains edge weights of `1.0` for each edge. How can I prevent this attribute from being added?

I realize I can write

```
for _,_,d in G.edges(data=True):
    d.clear()
```

but I would prefer if the attributes were not added in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do that with native networkx functions. This is how you can do it:

```
G = nx.empty_graph(0, nx.DiGraph)
G.add_nodes_from(range(A.shape[0]))
G.add_edges_from(((int(e[0]), int(e[1])) for e in zip(*A.nonzero())))
```

This is exactly how the `nx.convert_matrix.from_numpy_array` function is implemented internally. I got however rid of all controls, so be careful with this. Additional details can be found [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/convert_matrix.html#from_numpy_array)